Shopware 6.6 mixed content error when using reverse proxy
My Shopware runs on port 8080 using the HTTP protocol. Now I am using Caddy 2 as a reverse proxy. Both store and admin resources can be accessed normally, but I encounter a Mixed Content error when logging into the admin backend.
I found that the API context is using the HTTP protocol
<script nonce="z2Z0tu++HTU=">
                Shopware.Application.start({
            apiContext: {
                host: 'mydomian.com',
                port: 80,
                scheme: 'http',
                schemeAndHttpHost: 'http://mydomian.com',
                uri: 'http://mydomian.com/admin',
                basePath: '',
                pathInfo: '/admin',
                liveVersionId: '0fa91ce3e96a4bc2be4bd9ce752c3425',
                systemLanguageId: '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b',
                apiVersion: 4,
                assetPath: 'https://mydomian.com'
            },
            appContext: {
                features: window._features_,
                firstRunWizard: false,
                systemCurrencyId: 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
                systemCurrencyISOCode: 'USD',
                disableExtensions: false,
                adminEsEnable: false,
                storefrontEsEnable: false,
            }
        });
    </script>


Should I configure port 8080 to use the HTTPS protocol, or can I configure Caddy to handle this correctly?
my caddy config
:8080 {
    root * /var/www/data/public
    file_server
    encode gzip
    php_fastcgi unix//run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock
    ...
    ...
}
mydomian.com {
    reverse_proxy :8080 {
        header_up Host mydomian.com
        header_up X-Forwarded-Proto https
    }
}


I think you should first of all use HTTPS URLs in your apiContext ...? You did specify a HTTPS URL for assetPath, but everything else is HTTP. The proxy can't do anything about your app deliberately requesting an HTTP URL instead of an HTTPS one.

How should I set the URLs in apiContext to HTTPS? Should I do it through Caddy, or should I upgrade the port 8080 to HTTPS? @CBroe

"Should I do it through Caddy" - no, as I already said, the proxy can't do anything about the client trying to request the wrong URL to begin with. The client needs to make all its requests to https://mydomian.com to begin with, otherwise you'll get the mixed content warnings. So replace every http you got inside apiContext with https, and the port: 80 with port: 443. (Not sure if the latter is actually still necessary; you might be able to completely leave out the port part, when using default ports, I would assume.)

I've modified Caddy to not use a proxy, but now I want to forward the subdomain api.mydomain.com to paths starting with mydomain.com/api/. Using a proxy didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?
code
api.mydomian.com {
rewrite * /api{uri}
reverse_proxy mydomian.com
}
code
